# Python code performance on big data os.path.getsize

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, os.walk

Below is my code to get file size in ascending order.

```
def Create_Files_Structure(directoryname):
   for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directoryname,followlinks=False):
        subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
        try:
           files_list.extend([(os.path.join(path, file),os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, file))) for file in files ])
        except Exception as e:
            print()
   files_list.sort(key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)
   for pair in files_list:
     print(pair)
   print(len(files_list))

start=time.time()
Create_Files_Structure("/home/<username>")
end=time.time()
print(end-start)
```

This code is working however performance is slow if size of a directory is in TB or PB. Any suggestion to improve the code to get faster result please.

Comment: as your code is working, a better place for these type of questions is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get a feel for how fast you can get, try running and timing `du -k` on the directory. You probably won't be getting faster than that with Python for a full listing.
2. If you're running on Python < 3.5, try upgrading or using [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) for a nice performance improvement.
3. If you don't really need the whole list of files but can live with e.g the largest 1000 files:

Avoid keeping the list and use [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) with a generator

```
def get_sizes(root):
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('.')]
    for file in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        try:
          # keeping the size first means no need for a key function
          # which can affect performance
          yield (os.path.getsize(full_path), full_path)
        except Exception:
          pass

import heapq
for (size, name) in heapq.nlargest(1000, get_sizes(r"c:\some\path")):
  print(name, size)
```

EDIT - to get even faster on Windows - `os.scandir` yields entries that already contain the size helping avoid another system call.

This means using `os.scandir` and recursing yourself instead of relying on `os.walk` which doesn't yield that information.

There's a similar working example `get_tree_size()` function in the [scandir PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/#examples) that can be easily modified to yield names and sizes instead. Each entry's size is accessible with `entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size`.

Comment: Did you mean > Python 3.5?

Comment: @brandonscript in Python >= 3.5 it's built-in, in older versions you would consider the library I linked that made it into the standard library

Comment: Yeah, sorry. In your 2. You use < instead of >=, and the way it was worded made it sound like you could use scandir if you’re on 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Understood. I was answering in the context of the question which was looking for suggestions to make the code faster: upgrading to 3.5+ would make `os.walk` faster thanks to the underlying use of `scandir`, and using scandir directly as an external module would give the same effect for versions before 3.5. Maybe I could have been clearer

Answer (score 0):

**Nice Question** Try This :

```
import time, os

def create_files_structuredire_2(ctoryname):

    files_list = []
    counter = 0

    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(ctoryname):

        for items in filenames:

            file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))
            get_size = os.path.getsize(file_full_path)
            files_list.append((file_full_path, get_size))
            counter += 1

    files_list.sort(key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)
    [print(f) for f in files_list]
    print(counter)


start = time.time()
create_files_structuredire_2("your_target_folder")
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

**NOTE : your time is 0.044736385345458984, my time is 0.001501321792602539 !!!!!!**

Good Luck ...

Comment: You're not filtering the '.' subdirs from the scan - try timing it with that to compare